# How to use pjsip for windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have followed all the steps exactly given in this link  http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Windows-Phone, but I ended up with the following errors:

```
Error   1   Metadata file 'C:\Users\user\Documents\PJSIP\pjsip-apps\src\pjsua\wp\lib\PjsuaWP.BackEnd.winmd' could not be found  C:\Users\user\Documents\PJSIP\pjsip-apps\src\pjsua\wp\pjsua_wp\CSC  pjsua_wp
Error   2   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'wspiapi.h': No such file or directory   c:\program files (x86)\windows phone kits\8.0\include\ws2tcpip.h    1032    1   pjlib
Error   3   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'wspiapi.h': No such file or directory   c:\program files (x86)\windows phone kits\8.0\include\ws2tcpip.h    1032    1   pjlib
Error   25  error C2065: 'TLS_OUT_OF_INDEXES' : undeclared identifier   c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\pjlib\src\pj\os_core_win32.c  860 1   pjlib
Error   38  error C2065: 'CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO' : undeclared identifier   c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\pjlib\src\pj\os_core_win32.c  1525    1   pjlib
Error   39  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'info'    c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\pjlib\src\pj\os_core_win32.c  1525    1   pjlib
Error   40  error C2065: 'info' : undeclared identifier c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\pjlib\src\pj\os_core_win32.c  1525    1   pjlib
Error   42  error C2065: 'info' : undeclared identifier c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\pjlib\src\pj\os_core_win32.c  1529    1   pjlib
Error   43  error C2065: 'info' : undeclared identifier c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\pjlib\src\pj\os_core_win32.c  1530    1   pjlib
Error   44  error C2224: left of '.wAttributes' must have struct/union type c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\pjlib\src\pj\os_core_win32.c  1530    1   pjlib
Error   45  error C2198: 'os_attr_to_pj_color' : too few arguments for call c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\pjlib\src\pj\os_core_win32.c  1530    1   pjlib
Error   53  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'wspiapi.h': No such file or directory   c:\program files (x86)\windows phone kits\8.0\include\ws2tcpip.h    1032    1   pjmedia
Error   75  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'PaWinMME_GetStreamInputHandle'  c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\include\pa_win_wmme.h   154 1   libportaudio
Error   76  error C2059: syntax error : ';' c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\include\pa_win_wmme.h   154 1   libportaudio
Error   77  error C2059: syntax error : 'type'  c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\include\pa_win_wmme.h   154 1   libportaudio
Error   78  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'PaWinMME_GetStreamOutputHandle' c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\include\pa_win_wmme.h   179 1   libportaudio
Error   79  error C2059: syntax error : ';' c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\include\pa_win_wmme.h   179 1   libportaudio
Error   80  error C2059: syntax error : 'type'  c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\include\pa_win_wmme.h   179 1   libportaudio
Error   81  error C2065: 'FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER' : undeclared identifier   c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\hostapi\wmme\pa_win_wmme.c  335 1   libportaudio
Error   86  error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'  c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\hostapi\wmme\pa_win_wmme.c  524 1   libportaudio
rror    101 error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\hostapi\wmme\pa_win_wmme.c  577 1   libportaudio
Error   104 error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'  c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\hostapi\wmme\pa_win_wmme.c  638 1   libportaudio
Error   105 error C2081: 'WAVEFORMATEX' : name in formal parameter list illegal c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\hostapi\wmme\pa_win_wmme.c  638 1   libportaudio
ErroError   152 error C2224: left of '.dwFormats' must have struct/union type   c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\hostapi\wmme\pa_win_wmme.c  769 1   libportaudio
Error   154 error C2065: 'QueryInputWaveFormatEx' : undeclared identifier   c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\hostapi\wmme\pa_win_wmme.c  772 1   libportaudio
Error   155 error C2065: 'deviceInfo' : undeclared identifier   c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\hostapi\wmme\pa_win_wmme.c  772 1   libportaudio
Error   156 error C2223: left of '->maxInputChannels' must point to struct/union    c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\hostapi\wmme\pa_win_wmme.c  772 1   libportaudio
Error   157 error C2065: 'MMRESULT' : undeclared identifier c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\hostapi\wmme\pa_win_wmme.c  820 1   libportaudio
Error   158 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'mmresult'    c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\hostapi\wmme\pa_win_wmme.c  820 1   libportaudio
ErrorError  180 error C2224: left of '.szPname' must have struct/union type c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\hostapi\wmme\pa_win_wmme.c  853 1   libportaudio
Error   193 error C2065: 'WAVE_FORMAT_PCM' : undeclared identifier  c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  51  1   libportaudio
Error   194 error C2099: initializer is not a constant  c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  51  1   libportaudio
Error   195 error C2065: 'WAVEFORMATEX' : undeclared identifier c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  66  1   libportaudio
Error   196 error C2065: 'waveFormatEx' : undeclared identifier c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  66  1   libportaudio
Error   197 error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  66  1   libportaudio
Error   198 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'   c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  67  1   libportaudio
or  212 error C2065: 'bytesPerFrame' : undeclared identifier    c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  74  1   libportaudio
Error   213 error C2065: 'waveFormatEx' : undeclared identifier c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  75  1   libportaudio
Error   214 error C2223: left of '->wBitsPerSample' must point to struct/union  c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  75  1   libportaudio
EError  224 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'guid'    c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  87  1   libportaudio
Error   225 error C2065: 'guid' : undeclared identifier c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  87  1   libportaudio
Error   226 error C2065: 'waveFormatEx' : undeclared identifier c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  89  1   libportaudio
Error   227 error C2223: left of '->wFormatTag' must point to struct/union  c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  89  1   libportaudio
Error   228 error C2065: 'waveFormatEx' : undeclared identifier c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  90  1   libportaudio
Error   229 error C2223: left of '->nChannels' must point to struct/union   c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  90  1   libportaudio
or  235 error C2065: 'bytesPerFrame' : undeclared identifier    c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  92  1   libportaudio
Error   236 error C2065: 'waveFormatEx' : undeclared identifier c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  93  1   libportaudio
Error   237 error C2223: left of '->nBlockAlign' must point to struct/union c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  93  1   libportaudio
Error   238 error C2065: 'bytesPerFrame' : undeclared identifier    c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  93  1   libportaudio
Error   239 error C2065: 'waveFormatEx' : undeclared identifier c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  94  1   libportaudio
Error   240 error C2223: left of '->wBitsPerSample' must point to struct/union  c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  94  1   libportaudio
Error   241 error C2065: 'bytesPerSample' : undeclared identifier   c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  94  1   libportaudio
Error   242 error C2065: 'waveFormatEx' : undeclared identifier c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  95  1   libportaudio
Error   243 error C2223: left of '->cbSize' must point to struct/union  c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  95  1   libportaudio
Error   244 error C2065: 'waveFormatEx' : undeclared identifier c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  98  1   libportaudio
Error   245 error C2223: left of '->wBitsPerSample' must point to struct/union  c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  98  1   libportaudio
Error   246 error C2065: 'guid' : undeclared identifier c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  102 1   libportaudio
Error   247 error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'GUID' to 'int'  c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  102 1   libportaudio
Error   248 error C2065: 'guid' : undeclared identifier c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  103 1   libportaudio
Error   249 error C2224: left of '.Data1' must have struct/union type   c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  103 1   libportaudio
Error   250 error C2065: 'guid' : undeclared identifier c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  104 1   libportaudio
Error   251 error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'GUID'  c:\users\user\documents\pjsip\third_party\portaudio\src\os\win\pa_win_waveformat.c  104 1   libportaudio
Error   252 error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\Users\user\Documents\PJSIP\pjlib-util\lib\pjlib-util-i386-Win32-vc11-Debug.lib'   C:\Users\user\Documents\PJSIP\pjsip-apps\build\LINK libpjproject
Error   253 error U1073: don't know how to make '..\..\pjsip\lib\pjsip-core-i386-win32-vc11-debug.lib'  C:\Users\user\Documents\PJSIP\pjsip-apps\build\NMAKE    samples
Error   254 error MSB3073: The command "nmake /NOLOGO /S /f Samples-vc.mak BUILD_MODE=debug VC_VER=11 ARCH=win32 /a" exited with code 2.    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets   43  5   samples
Error   255 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'iphlpapi.lib'  C:\Users\user\Documents\PJSIP\pjsip-apps\build\LINK sample_debug
Error   256 error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'wspiapi.h': No such file or directory   c:\program files (x86)\windows phone kits\8.0\include\ws2tcpip.h
```

Please help me to solve this problem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you switch to Windows Runtime. There's a work to do but all this issues can be solved. I'm succesfully using pjsip in Universal App with some small changes.

One of your troubles is that you're compiling portaudio. Follow the guideline:

```
#define PJMEDIA_AUDIO_DEV_HAS_PORTAUDIO 0
#define PJMEDIA_AUDIO_DEV_HAS_WMME 0
#define PJMEDIA_AUDIO_DEV_HAS_WASAPI 1
```

But that's only the first step